# Why is my glReadPixels program not working in another computer?

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am making chess in opengl as a learning exercise. My idea is to use glReadPixels for object picking(in my case being the chess pieces). However the code only seems to work properly on my laptop and not on my desktop.

Before working with actual movement I setup a simple outlining of the object.

I have a mouse class which calculates mouse position and returns the color of the pixel at the mouse location.

I have a class for each piece where I generate a random color and position for each piece and store them in position and color arrays.

I have a game class which calls the mouse class function to get the color at the mouse location. It then compares this color value with the colors stored in the arrays of each piece. Wherever the color matches, it calls a handleHit function of that class with the index argument. It uses this index to determine the position of the piece from the position array and accordingly does outlining.

```
Mouse Class :  
static void calcMousePos(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    int width, height;
    double x, y;
    glfwGetWindowSize(window, &width, &height);
    glfwGetCursorPos(window, &x, &y);
    position.x = x;
    position.y = y;
}
static glm::vec3 getPixelColorUnderMouse(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    calcMousePos(window);
    float data[3];
    glReadPixels(position.x, SCR_HEIGHT - position.y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, data);
    glm::vec3 color;
    color.r = data[0];
    color.g = data[1];
    color.b = data[2];
    std::cout << color.r << " " << color.g << " " << color.b << std::endl;
    return color;
}

Game Class:
void checkObjectWithCurrentColor(const glm::vec3 &color)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        if (color == pawn->getPawnColor(i))
        {
            pawn->handleHit(i);
            break;
        }
        if (i < 4)
        {
            if (color == rook->getRookColor(i))
            {
                rook->handleHit(i);
                break;
            }
            else if (color == knight->getKnightColor(i))
            {
                knight->handleHit(i);
                break;
            }
            else if (color == bishop->getBishopColor(i))
            {
                bishop->handleHit(i);
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i < 2)
        {
            if (color == queen->getQueenColor(i))
            {
                queen->handleHit(i);
                break;
            }
            else if (color == king->getKingColor(i))
            {
                king->handleHit(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This piece of code gives me correct outlining on all pieces when I execute the program in my laptop but works erratically in my desktop. On some pieces it does outlining but on others it doesn't. The outlining also changes based on window position. I tried outputting the color values of my pieces and the color values at the mouse location. They both match but the if else part of checkObjectWithCurrentColor() for some reason fails to execute on my desktop for most of the pieces.

P.S. Not using any intermediate framebuffer for pixel reading.

Comment: _for some reason fails to execute_ is a quite vague problem description. Can you be more concrete please?

Comment: You need to extract  a [mcve] from your code for posting here. Chances are that you'll find the error yourself while doing that, which is exactly why it is mandatory for "why doesn't the code work?" type of questions. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. BTW: Check out what "magic numbers" are!

Answer (score 0):

It was just a float precision problem. The values returned by glReadPixels and the values stored in the arrays varied slightly in the last decimal places. I fixed it by storing int values in the arrays and also converting the glReadPixels values to int.